# phpMyadmin can't set default value to Null

Tags: mysql

How to set varchar, text, int default to NULL in Mysql?

I have a table, some columns are optional for the user to fill.

I want to set the default to NULL if the user didn't fill any thing.

I try to do it in PHPMyAdmin, but I got error `#1067 - Invalid default value`

[image]

Comment: Give an example of the column. Is it filled with data.. You need to add more details.

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: i do it in phpMyadmin, i use mouse click select option

Comment: Did you uncheck the `NULL`-checkbox (between `ATTRIBUTE` and `INDEX`)?

Comment: Columns need to be nullable.

Comment: I have Default set to NULL and NULL box is checked. But, still under Structure in PHPMyAdmin it is showing as blank field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the option Null for the column be checked.

[image]

Comment: That's not enough.
I got a "you can not set a default value on a blob"